# $ \displaystyle \int_{M \times N} (\pi^*_M \alpha) \wedge(\pi^*_N \beta) = \int_M ( \alpha) \int_N ( \beta) $.

Tags: integration, manifolds, differential

How can i solve this problem? Unfortunately i have no ideas...

Let M, N oriented manifolds, $\alpha \in \Lambda^{\text{dim}(M)}(M)$ and $\beta \in \Lambda^{\text{dim}(N)}(N)$ differential forms with compact support. Let $\pi_M: M \times N \rightarrow M $ and  $\pi_N: M \times N \rightarrow N $, the natural projections. Show that

$ \displaystyle \int_{M \times N} (\pi^*_M \alpha) \wedge(\pi^*_M \beta) = \int_M ( \alpha) \int_N ( \beta)  $

Comment: Hint: write, in local coordinates $(x^1,\ldots,x^m,y^1,\ldots,y^n)$, where $(x^i)$ are coordinates on $M$ and $(y^j)$ on $N$, the integrals.

Comment: I think that i find an "solution" using that, but i'm not sure how to get two integrals from the first one, need i use the Rn results? Maybe Fubini...?

Comment: Can you write a proof for this? @Didier Leandro C. Araújo

Comment: I can send you what i did! Isn't perfect, so you can fix it and show the right answer here.

Comment: Yes please @Leandro C. Araújo

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hk7-Kxh45qYX1bmbpNdnaM2FxP1TtpD6/view?usp=sharing)